# Methods on an object modifies an attribute of an other object

Tags: java, object, attributes, runtime-error

I can't understand why when I work on an instance of 'Distribuzione' it is modified the parametre 'medie' of an other instance. Here is the part of code where I work with objects 'Distribuzioni':

```
Distribuzione bernulliana = new Distribuzione(f, popolazione, f.getDefTabBernulli());
Distribuzione inBlocco = new Distribuzione(f, popolazione, f.getDefTabInBlocco());

f.getMediaCampBlocco().setText(String.valueOf(inBlocco.calcoloMedia(inBlocco.getMedie())));
f.getMediaCampRipetizione().setText(String.valueOf(bernulliana.calcoloMedia(bernulliana.getMedie())));
f.getVarCampBlocco().setText(String.valueOf(inBlocco.calcoloVarianza(inBlocco.getMedie())));
f.getVarCampRipetizione().setText(String.valueOf(bernulliana.calcoloVarianza(bernulliana.getMedie())));

inBlocco.mediaCampionaria(f.getDefTabMedInBlocco());
bernulliana.mediaCampionaria(f.getDefTabMedBernulli());
```

Every object of class 'Distribuzione' has inside the vector 'medie', and when I call methods of the object 'inBlocco', they modify the attribute 'medie' of the object 'bernulliana'.
It seems that the same vector 'medie' is used by both the object. Why? How can I create two different vectors one for every instance of 'Distribuzione'?

Here is the code of class 'Distribuzione' :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Distribuzione {

public Vector<Float> getMedie() {
    return medie;
}

private static Grafica f = null;
private static Vector<Float> medie;
private static DefaultTableModel tabella;

public Distribuzione(Grafica f, Vector<Float> popolazione, DefaultTableModel tabella){
    this.f = f;
    medie = new Vector<Float>();
    this.tabella = tabella;
    creaDistribuzione(f.getNcampione(), 0, popolazione, new Vector<Float>());
}

private static String vectorToString(Vector<Float> vector){
    //istanzio una nuova stringa che inizializzo con una parentesi aperta
    String stringaCampione = new String("(");

    for(int x = 0; x < vector.size(); x++)
        stringaCampione = stringaCampione.concat(Float.toString(vector.elementAt(x)).concat(", "));

    stringaCampione = stringaCampione.substring(0, stringaCampione.length()-2);
    stringaCampione = stringaCampione.concat(")");
    return (stringaCampione);
}

public Float calcoloMedia(Vector<Float> vet){
    float sum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < vet.size(); x++) sum += vet.elementAt(x);
    return sum / vet.size();
}

public Float calcoloVarianza(Vector<Float> vet){
    float media = calcoloMedia(vet);
    float varianza = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < vet.size(); x++) varianza += Math.pow(vet.elementAt(x) - media, 2);
    return varianza / vet.size();
}

private void creaDistribuzione(int n, int primoElementoConsiderato, Vector<Float> popolazione, Vector<Float> combinazione){
    if(n==0){
        Vector<String> riga = new Vector<String>();

        riga.add(vectorToString(combinazione));

        int sum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < combinazione.size(); x++) sum += combinazione.elementAt(x);
        float media = (float) sum / combinazione.size();
        riga.add(String.valueOf(media));
        this.medie.add(media);

        this.tabella.addRow(riga);
        return;
    }

    for(int x = primoElementoConsiderato; x<popolazione.size();x++){
        Vector<Float> aggiunta = new Vector<Float>(combinazione);
        aggiunta.add(popolazione.elementAt(x));
        if(this.tabella == f.getDefTabInBlocco()){
            creaDistribuzione(n-1, x+1, popolazione, aggiunta);
        }else{
            creaDistribuzione(n-1, 0, popolazione, aggiunta);
        }           
    }
}

public void mediaCampionaria(DefaultTableModel dafTabMed){
    Float valore;
    int count;

    Collections.sort(this.medie);

    while(this.medie.size() > 0){
        Vector<String> riga = new Vector<String>();
        count = 1;
        valore = this.medie.remove(0);

        while(this.medie.size() > 0 && this.medie.elementAt(0).equals(valore)){
            this.medie.remove(0);
            count++;
        }

        riga.add(String.valueOf(valore));
        riga.add(String.valueOf(count));    
        dafTabMed.addRow(riga);
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the 'static' clausole. 'static' means that that one is a common attribute between every instance of the class, and if in one of them you modify that attribute, it is modified also in the others.